# heroku redis:info -a sushi returns nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis

I want to upgrade my Redis addon on Heroku. However, when I run `heroku redis:info -a botletter`, the terminal does not return anything.

When I run `heroku addons`, I see the following line:

> redistogo-rugged-99398      redistogo:nano                free

Then `heroku addons:info redistogo-rugged-99398` outputs:

> Installed at: Sat Jul 01 2017 16:19:36 GMT+0200 (CEST) 
>   Owning app:  botletter 
>   Plan:         redistogo:nano 
>   Price:        free 
>   State:      created

Why does `heroku redis:info -a botletter` not ouptut anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`heroku redis:info`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#upgrading-a-heroku-redis-instance) is a command for [*Heroku's own* Redis addon](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis). You're using [Redis To Go](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo), an entirely separate Redis addon provided by Rackspace.

As you've discovered, you can use `heroku addons:info` to see information about the addon you're using.